# ionic: Can't navigate back to cached view using $ionicHistory.goBack()

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-view

I have a state defined as follows:

```
.state('tab.friends-userprofile', {
    url: '/friendsUserprofile/:id',
    views: {
       'tab-friends': {
       templateUrl: 'templates/social/userprofile.html',
       controller: 'ProfileCtrl'
       }
    }
 })
```

Think of something like Facebook where you can navigate from one Friend A, to Friend B to Friend C, using the same state (but different instances - as given by the id parameter).

My problem is that when I navigate from Friend A to Friend B to Friend C, then **back** to Friend B using the back button (i.e. `$ionicHistory.goBack()`). The cached view of friend B is not returned, instead there is a transition, but the page content stays on Friend C.

Comment: I've not seen this behaviour and my users can traverse fairly deep with states in Ionic. Any other code you can share of significance? Perhaps a closer look at where you call `goBack()`. What version of Ionic are you running?

Comment: I'm using the latest Ionic 1.2.4. Perhaps I somehow broke the history because of some custom stuff I did. But the history seems fine when I check the history it seems fine when check it via `$ionicHistory.viewHistory()` but when I go back my scope is not reloaded.
The custom code I have was to achive button-bar tabs [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35672436/how-can-i-forward-using-ionichistory-in-ionic) - I posted about it a while back.